# Тестирование алгоритмов сортировки массива

Tags: алгоритм

Здравствуйте. 
Есть задание реализовать сортировку методами пузырька и вставкой в прямом и обернутом виде — это сделал, реализовал создание массива указаной размерности и заполнение его случайными числами.

Дальше требуется: Провести тестирование алгоритмов на различных наборах данных. Тестирование 
проводится для размеров данных [10, 100, 1000, 10000] и трех типов входных данных (случайно сгенерированные входные данные, лучшие и худшие входные данные). Сравнить полученные результаты тестирования.

Здесь немного запутался, если под <<случайно сгенерированные входные данные>> имеется ввиду массив с рандомными значениями, то что имеется ввиду под: <<лучшие и худшие входные данные>>?

Спасибо заранее.

Comment: @qwesc, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Скорее всего речь идет о том, насколько упорядоченными были входные данные изначально. То есть лучший случай - это когда входной массив уже отсортирован, а худший - это когда он отсортирован в порядке, обратном нужному

Answer (score 5):

Подумайте, как будут вести себя эти и другие алгоритмы сортировки для таких случаев входных данных (иногда вырожденных) как:

- уже отсортированный массив;
- отсортированный в обратном порядке массив;
- частично упорядоченный массив;
- массив с повторяющимися элементами;
- массив, все значения которого одинаковы.